# Oracle Procedure to insert all records from one staging table into main table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I wrote `Stored Procedure (SP)` where inside SP, 2 SP separated for 2 insertion from table. Both table contains more than 25 columns in each temp & main table. Below is query-

```
create or replace procedure sp_main as

 procedure tbl1_ld as 
  cursor c1 is select * from tmp1;
  type t_rec1 is table of c1%rowtype;
  v_rec1 t_rec1;
 begin
  open c1;
  loop
   fetch c1 bulk collect into v_rec1 limit 1000;
   exit when v_rec1.count=0;
   insert into tbl1 values v_rec1;
  end loop;
 end tbl1_ld;

 procedure tbl2_ld as 
  cursor c2 is select * from tmp2;
  type t_rec2 is table of c2%rowtype;
  v_rec2 t_rec2;
 begin
  open c2;
  loop
   fetch c2 bulk collect into v_rec2 limit 1000;
   exit when v_rec2.count=0;
   insert into tbl2 values v_rec2;
  end loop;
 end tbl2_ld;

begin
 null;
end sp_main;
/
```

I used `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into tbl1 select * from tmp1';` for insertion inside both SP `tbl1_ld & tbl2_ld` instead of using `cursor`, SP compiled but no record has been inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you didn't actually run any of these procedures. The last few lines of your code should be

```
  <snip>
  end tbl2_ld;

begin
  tbl1_ld;      --> this
  tbl2_ld       --> this
end sp_main;
/
```

---

On the other hand, I prefer avoiding `insert into ... select * from` because it just loves to fail when you modify tables' description and don't fix code that uses those tables.

Yes, I know - it is just *boring* to name all 25 columns, but - in my opinion - it's worth it. Therefore, I'd just

```
begin
  insert into tbl1 (id, name, address, phone, ... all 25 columns)
  select id, name, address, phone, ... all 25 columns
  from tmp1;

  insert into tbl2 (id, name, address, phone, ... all 25 columns)
  select id, name, address, phone, ... all 25 columns
  from tmp2;
end;
```

In other words, no cursors, types, loops, ... nothing. Could have been pure SQL (i.e. no PL/SQL). If you want to restrict number of rows inserted, use e.g. `... where rownum <= 1000` (if that's why you used the `limit` clause).

---

As of dynamic SQL you mentioned (`execute immediate`): **why** would you use it? There's nothing dynamic in code you wrote.

Comment: *"because it just loves to fail when you modify tables' description and don't fix code that uses those tables"*. A different way of looking at things is that this is a feature not a bug. Sometimes we need table structures to stay in sync; in a warehouse we might have temporary staging tables and permanent archive tables which should have matching projections. In such cases the use of `select * from ` acts as a canary to remind us to change both tables. I concede this is not a common use case but it is one I have come across, and it looks like it might fit the Seeker's scenario.